# Dot notation vs. Bracket Notation

Tags: javascript, object, brackets

Why does dot notation not delete the key using javascript but bracket notation does?

```js
    function removeProperty(obj, key) {
      // your code here
    delete obj.key;
        
     }
    
    var obj = {
      name: 'Sam',
      age: 20
    }
    console.log(obj.name);
    removeProperty(obj, 'name');
    console.log(obj.name); // --> undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is frankly bit unclear but I will try to answer it based on my understanding

To delete a key from object we do something like this

```js
  var obj = {
      name: 'Sam',
      age: 20
    }


delete obj.name 

console.log(obj) // won't have name
```

Now In your function,

```
   function removeProperty(obj, key) {
      // your code here
    delete obj.key;
        
     }
```

You are trying to delete a property `key` from obj which does not exist.

Correct way would've been

```
   function removeProperty(obj, key) {
      // your code here
    delete obj[key]
  
     }
```

So, the correct way to delete inside a function in case of your code snippet would be

```js
function removeProperty(obj, key) {
      // your code here
    delete obj[key];
        
     }
    
    var obj = {
      name: 'Sam',
      age: 20
    }
    console.log(obj.name);
    removeProperty(obj, 'name');
    console.log(obj.name); // --> undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem with your function `removeProperty` is that you can't use dot notation with a variable.

```
let attributeName
obj.attributeName
```

This example is invalid.

Instead you can use a string variable with brackets notation.

```
let attributeName
obj[attruteName]
```

This example is valid.

Answer (score -1):

let obj = {
'my name': 'ersath',
name:'ersath'
}

console.log(obj['my name'])
console.log(obj.name)

// bracket notation used for this scenerio

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).